# In Office add-in, where is the taskpane.js script being loaded?

Tags: html, ms-word, office365, office-js, office-addins

I am following the sample of a simple Word Office Add-in. In the taskpane folder, there is a taskpane.js but the taskpane.html only has the following script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
```

It seems like the taskpane.js is not being loaded? Where is the taskpane.js loaded?

Comment: Does your manifest file refer to the taskpane.js file?

Comment: no it refers to taskpane.html instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack does that for you!

If you go to the `webpack.config.js` file you may find the following plugin declaration:

```
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "taskpane"],
      }),
```

Which adds the required references to the HTML page when the add-in is built.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Eugene's answer. The `webpack.config.js` in root also has the code that load the JavaScript file:

```
entry: {
  polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
  taskpane: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.js",
  commands: "./src/commands/commands.js",
},
```